# How do I create a banner panel in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, panel

I want to create my own custom control that is basically a TableLayoutPanel with 3 rows and 1 column.  The top and bottom rows will contain labels (banners) and the middle row is where I will add other controls.  The problem is that when I try to build other forms/controls from this control, the designer doesn't recognize the middle panel.  How do I get it to?  If I drag a textbox to the middle and set Dock=Fill, it will cover the entrie form/control.  Also, is there any way to get the designer to reject dragging of controls to the top and bottom (banner) rows?  I've tried the steps in the following link but haven't had any luck (http://support.microsoft.com/?scid=kb%3Ben-us%3B813450&x=21&y=15).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out.  The trick was to create my own designer that inherits from ParentControlDesigner and overrides the Initialize method and calls EnableDesignMode for the inner content panel.  On top of this, I needed to set the Designer attribute of my user control to this new designer.  The details are shown [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/514094-usercontrol-container-panel-problems).

One problem, though.  I can drag controls to the content panel I created and everything looks fine.  But, once I recompile, the controls disappear.  They are still there, I just think they're getting drawn before the banner panel.  I will create a separate thread for this problem.