# Why are controls within custom panel (C# winforms) disappearing in designer?

Tags: c#, user-controls, panel

I have been able to create a custom C# winforms control that is basically a panel with a fixed banner (header/footer).  I want to base other user controls on this "banner panel".  I've gotten past the problem with the designer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1460162/how-do-i-create-a-banner-panel-in-c).  I can successfully add controls to the inner content panel.  Everything looks fine while designing.  However, when I recompile, the controls I added to the content panel disappear.  They are still there (in code) but aren't displayed in the designer.  Is there any thing that I need to do to set the drawing order of the controls?

Comment: I'd like an answer to this as well if anyone has it.

Answer (score 1):

Your controls are still nested correctly within the panel control, they have just lost their z-order.  If you choose the controls from the property panel and right click on the control border that appears within the parent panel and select "Bring To Front" from the layout toolbar, your nested controls will re-appear.  I don't know why it does this, but a workaround is to bring all child controls to the front during control initialization in the code.

Answer (score 0):

There is really nothing to go on here without src.  What I would do is to comment everything out including in the InitializeComponent function but a widget in the middle panel and run.  Do whatever it takes to get that one widget to show.  Inherit from UserControl instead of the banner panel.

Then comment in each piece until the widget no longer comes up.  That is what is causing your problems.  Once it all comes up properly, then you make sure the designer portion of the src works.  It is going to potentially be a long process.